# Android ListView Adapter changing the inflated layout later

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I've 3 listview item layouts.
By reopen the activity it is work without bugs, but if I add a item by clicking to a button the layout is not changing, because row != null.
I hope you can understand me with my bad english.

```
        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    int layout = 0;

    if(chatMessageObj.centered) {
        layout = R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage_center;
    } else {
        layout = chatMessageObj.left ? R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage_left : R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage;
    }

    if (row == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is to create only one list view item: `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation and 3 children:

`- R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage_left,
 - R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage_center, 
 - R.layout.activity_chat_singlemessage`

and in your `getView()` method show relevant layout based on given condition and hide layouts that should not be shown.